# I want to bind an List of bool to DataGridRows (besides of the real data), one item to one grid row to use a datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know how to make this binding, each of the elements of the RoWVisibility should be binded to one dataGridRow. I post the most relevant parts of the code because the real one has about 400 lines, and I have checked that the filter logic works as expected.

```
public partial class AdvancedDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public ObservableCollection<WPFBool> RowVisibility { get; set; }

    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((DataView)(this.ItemsSource)).ToTable().Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            RowVisibility.Add(new WPFBool());
        }
    }

    // A lot of filter logic that works because I checked that the filtered items are false 
    // in row visibility with the debuger
}
```

This is the WPFBool definition

```
public class WPFBool : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _value = true;
    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged("Value"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the affected XAML (the dataGrid has a x:Name = dataGrid, that's the reason of the source inside the binding)

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowVisibility, Source={Source={x:Reference dataGrid}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

If you need anything more, I will post it. Thank you.

Comment: Is `RowVisibility` the `ItemsSource` of the datagridview? It looks weird that you refer to the parent `dataGrid` from within a RowStyle to determine visibility. Define your bool on the Item itself.

Comment: No its not, the `ItemsSource` comes from a `DataTable` that I don't want to modify with an extra column because it's used in other parts of the code.  And I defined the bool in the codebehind of `AdvancedDataGrid`, and as far as I know 2 `Itemssources` are not allowed.